# Froce-HLS with real iphones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-player

I always need hls.js to be load, i'm setting forceHLS key to (true).
Just through real iphone device react player not read hls.js file implemented.
Take in consideration that hls.js works normally through the iphone in the inspect element.
Thanks

Comment: Share your code, so other can know where is the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.